# How to add an service accessibility Android that registre Alert Dialog

Tags: accessibilityservice

I would Like to listen to Alert Dialog, and I have added an example but it doesn't work, and I can't follow the starting and capturing the event like Key Up ..etc by using Log.d.

I confirm that the Accessibility Service has Enabled, but I would like to to assure that is executing.

Here is my code:

```
public class MyService extends AccessibilityService {
 public static String TAG = "USD";
    @Override
    public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {

        Log.i(TAG, "onAccessibilityEvent: getting");
        String text = event.getText().toString();
        if (event.getClassName().equals("android.app.AlertDialog")) {
            Log.i(TAG,  " Getting USSD"+text);
            Toast.makeText(this, text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
 }
```

and the Manifest code

```
<service android:name=".MyService"
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE"
    android:label=""
    android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" />
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.accessibilityservice"
        android:resource="@xml/accessibility_service_config" />
</service>
```

And this is the config XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<accessibility-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:packageNames="com.android.phone"
android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeWindowStateChanged|typeWindowContentChanged"
android:accessibilityFlags="flagDefault"
android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackGeneric"
android:notificationTimeout="0"
android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"
android:canRequestFilterKeyEvents="true"
android:settingsActivity="com.example.android.accessibility.ServiceSettingsActivity"
    />
```